# "it modulo" meaning in Math context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, mathematics

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> Since the sum can be large, find it modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly parsed the sentence as

> Since the sum can be large, find || it modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.

whereas it should be

> Since the sum can be large, find it || modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.

The suggestion is to break down the sum by 1,000,000,007 into a *divisor* and *remainder*.

Comment: Thanks. What is `||`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `its` instead of `it`?

Comment: The || is just to show where your parsed the sentence.  The modulo does not belong to the answer, the sentence is saying "find it *by calculating* modulo^9 + 7".